# requests.get(url) doesn't work on some links of a blog

Tags: python

I am trying to parse few links from a blog and save their content in a dictionary. All the links work well in the browser. But in my `python` script, few links return `404` , few links return `200`. I am puzzled what's going on!
Here is the list of links:

```
https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/faith-based-rehab-treatment/
https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/
https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/what-qualifies-for-acute-rehab/
https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/
https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/rehab-clinic-faq/
https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/rehab-faq/
https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/5-reasons-rehab-cannot-help-you/
https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/how-rehab-works/
https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/private-alcohol-rehab-what-to-beware/
```

Here is my `python` script:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}

file1 = open(r'links.txt','r')
links = file1.readlines()
num_links = len(links)
blogs = ['blog' + str(i+1) for i in range(num_links)]
blogs_dict = {i:'' for i in blogs}


for i in links:
    url = i
    ind = links.index(i)
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if req.status_code in [200]:
        blogs_dict[ind] = req.text
        print(f'link {i} works well')
    else:
        print(f'link {i} doesn\'t work')

print(blogs_dict)
```

I had the links saved in a txt file named `links.txt`

This is the terminal output, showing which links work and which don't:

```
link https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/faith-based-rehab-treatment/
 doesn't work
link https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/
 works well
link https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/what-qualifies-for-acute-rehab/
 doesn't work
link https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/
 works well
link https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/rehab-clinic-faq/
 doesn't work
link https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/rehab-faq/
 doesn't work
link https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/5-reasons-rehab-cannot-help-you/
 doesn't work
link https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/how-rehab-works/
 doesn't work
link https://www.abbeycarefoundation.com/alcohol/alcohol-rehab/private-alcohol-rehab-what-to-beware/
 doesn't work
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show us wich links work and wich don't?

Comment: edit the question. added the links which don't work

Comment: Try `url = i.strip()`. `readlines()` returns the newlines at the end which... breaks links inconsistently. IDK why it doesn't break all of them.

Comment: worked very well! can you post it as an answer